# Context menu not working in recycler view

Tags: android, contextmenu

I'm trying to add context menu in recycler view but its not working.
in my adapter i added the following

```
  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
   View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
    TextView mTitle, mDescription;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        mDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                String title = mTitle.getText().toString();
                String descrpition = mDescription.getText().toString();
                if (mClickListener!=null)
                    mClickListener.onItemClick(v, position, title, descrpition);
            }
        });
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (onRecyclerViewLongClickListner!=null)
                    onRecyclerViewLongClickListner.onItemLongClick(position);
                return true;
            }
        });
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select options");
        menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,"Option1");
    }
}
```

and in mainActivity i added `registerForContextMenu(recyclerView);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is on your [OnLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener#onLongClick(android.view.View)). Its consuming long click event as you are returning true.

From `onLongClick` method documentation:

> true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise.

As you need to create `ContextMenu` in onLongClick so you have to return `false` from your `OnLongClickListener` so System can create `ContextMenu`.

Update your `OnLongClickListener`

```
  itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (onRecyclerViewLongClickListner!=null)
                onRecyclerViewLongClickListner.onItemLongClick(position);
              return false;
        }
    });
```